# C# Using Assignment Lists which Reference the Assigned Variable

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, lambda

Does anyone know a trick that would allow me to do something like this (where Function is a `Func<bool>`:

```
        UnaryNode<bool> compliment = new UnaryNode<bool>()
            { Function = () => !compliment.Right.Value };
```

The following works in place, but is not as nice.

```
        UnaryNode<bool> compliment = new UnaryNode<bool>();
        compliment.Function = () => !compliment.Right.Value;
```

Comment: I am using 4.0, if you know multiple ways, I would love to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not allowed, as documented in the [langauge specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029). Section 7.6.10.2:

> It is not possible for the object initializer to refer to the newly
>   created object it is initializing.

Nor do I find your second version in any way not "nice." As for a "trick," it would be something even more "ugly." You would need to create a temporary throwaway, and then rely upon lambdas closing over the variable instead of the value. For example, given:

```
class Foo
{
    public Func<bool> Function;     
    public Bar Bar;
}

class Bar
{
    public bool Value;
}
```

You could then have

```
// DO NOT try this at home
Foo foo = null; 
Foo temp = new Foo { Function = () => !foo.Bar.Value };
foo = temp;

bool result1 = foo.Function(); // true
foo.Bar.Value = true;
bool result2 = foo.Function(); // false
```

Is that more or less "nice" than what you already have?

Comment: This works because that particular expression is [lazily-evaluated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)... Are lamba always lazy evaluated?

Comment: @KileyNaro, it's not the lazy evaluation specifically, it's the closure over the *variable* foo and not foo's original *value*. People sometimes intuitively think they can close over `foo`, but that it's safe to reassign foo later and have that *not* reflect in their lambda, but that's not the case. See: [blogs like this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx). But, yes, the function itself evaluates the expression with each invocation.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Thanks for the blog link. Not only does this help me understand both the problem and the explanation a bit better, but it has made me realize that I could afford to do some research on closures.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can create a new class.

```
class ComplimentUnaryNode : UnaryNode<bool>
{
    public ComplimentUnaryNode()
    {
        Function = () => !Right.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Introducing inheritance and a new class to solve syntax preferences would be an overkill

Comment: Originally he talked about static initialization, though I no longer see that in the post. It seemed like something which is being used regularly.

Comment: thanks now is clear, I remember that there is was something regarding static initially